# c3.js time format in tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

I want to display the time format inside the tooltip for the [c3.js chart library](http://c3js.org/)

```
tooltip: {
   contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
      return "<p>" + d[0].x + "</p>" + "<p>" + d[0].value + "</p>"
   }
 }
```

This works :

[image]

but the time format is totally wrong although I defined the X axis tick format already:

```
x: {
   type: 'timeseries',
   label: false,
   tick: { format: '%d.%m %H:%M' }
},
```

So I have to reformate it again for the tooltip. But I have now idea how and I can't find anything in the [cs.js docs](http://c3js.org/reference.html).

So how do I have to format the tooltip tick ?

Comment: could you please setup jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a time series as x-axis, you will get JavaScript [Date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on the `x` property.

In order to format those, use the corresponding methods. I.e.

```
var formattedTime = d[0].x.getHours() + ":" + d[0].x.getMinutes();
```

For more convenient string formatting methods, I would recomment the [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) library:

```
var formattedTime = moment(d[0].x).format('HH:mm');
```

Comment: Thanks. I did it with moment.js